# why images are not loading from local XMl file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

While loading the images from local XML file like this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Books>
<book id="1">
<img>/Users/admin/imagefolder/Main_pic.png</img>
</book>
</Books>
```

Am parsing the file and it parse the image from file. I can see in NSLog output as

```
<UIImage: 0x71883d0>
```

but when i view it in iphone as UIImage view, no image is shown. i had set the image in viewDidLoad Method as like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/admin/imagefolder/Main_pic.png"];
       [theLists setImg:image];
   }
```

Where am doing wrong? how to get the image as output in UIImageView of iphone

**Edited:**

"theLists" is a object of the file where i had defined the UIImage Object say i have a file "list.h" like this, where i define the image

```
@interface list : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *img;
```

Now in the appdelegate.m file am importing the "list.h" and use like this,

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) list *theLists;
```

and this "thelists" is used in viewDidLoad()

**Edited-2**

My parsing code is here,

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
 egsParser *theParser =[[egsParser alloc] initParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:theParser];
```

Comment: How you are adding theLists on view? Check in IB if it is connected to image view properly.

Comment: How do you add your theLists to the view?

Comment: Are you sure you are using iOS? sandbox

Comment: Please give more info about theLists object and class.

Comment: what is theLists , how are you adding it to your view, where is that directory you are calling, and how are you displaying the log.

Comment: "thelists" is an object of file where i had defined the UIImage

Comment: Is the image really on `/Users/admin/imagefolder/Main_pic.png`?

Comment: where do you put data that you get from parser?

Answer (score 0):

If your images is stored in array you should use something like this code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(((list *)[yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]).img)]];
```

To access your data if you storing it as `NSString`. **i-number of image in array**

or

```
 UIImage *image = (((list *)[yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]).img);
```

If you getting it like `UIImage`

Comment: am not understanding how to use this as you posted but i copied these in my code it complies as error